# Cross-site XML access using javascript without server access

Tags: javascript, xml, cross-server

I asked a question earlier but did not word it correctly so it got brushed over.

Basically, I am creating a windows 7 gadget that will access XML data from www.weather.gov and display some current conditions.

```
        function weat()
        {

            var url = "http://www.weather.gov/xml/current_obs/KMSY.xml";


            source.open("GET", url, false);
            source.send(null);
            info = source.responseXML;

            document.write("<table border='1'>");
            var stuff = info.getElementsByTagName("temp_f");

            document.write("<tr><td>");
            document.write(stuff);
            document.write("</tr></td>");
            document.write("</table>");

        }
```

Basically I am trying to get this to work from my desktop, and I'm not totally sure what the problem is. I still think it is a cross-site problem, since stuff prints as undefined, but I'm not totally sure of that.  If anyone could help me, I've been googling possible solutions for about 6 hours now and I'm getting pretty frustrated.

Comment: Have you tried echoing `stuff`? What's in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need a server-side proxy or you need to find a weather service that supports [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: How would a proxy or JSONP help?

Comment: @Albireo, If you configure a web server on your own domain that proxies requests to weather.gov, your script can get the data from it's own domain thus avoiding the security restriction. JSONP works via `<script>` tags instead of XHR which is exempt from the cross-domain restriction.

Comment: A Windows' gadget does not have a domain, there is no such thing as "Same Origin Policy" (I'm saying this out of experience, I currently have a Windows 7 gadget I created which fetches a `text/plain` from a "outside" domain, and it works with a simple XHR).

Comment: @Albireo, Ah, it seems you are correct. OP marked me as correct though. Was this actually fixed or not?

Comment: Hmm. I still haven't quite fixed the problem, but I marked this as correct because I assumed this was impossible.  As of right now, it still doesn't quite work, but it's completely possible that the XML request is not the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Gadget. But in desktop browsers, I'm afraid [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) prevent from any cross domain access.

One exception is that in Chromium, local pages (file://) can access remote URL only if --disable-web-securities is set when starting Chromium in command line.

Comment: Windows' gadget does not enforce the same origin policy (BTW, there is no "domain" to begin with), they allow AJAX requests to any domain.